# Where could I find Greenland maps?

Tags: maps, greenland

I'm trying to find Greenland road or main trail maps. Also, if there are ferry lines that join Greenland cities it will be very useful. Any link?

Comment: Do you mean an online resource or published maps?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee An online resource is better for me, but a published map is also acceptable

Comment: Does OpenStreetMap contain enough map information for you?  http://osm.org/go/c88wESg--

Comment: The problem with OSM (and increased in Greenland) is that is difficult to know if the area is not mapped because nobody has mapped or if really there is no road there.

Comment: It might be a great feature to suggest to OSM to somehow indicate known unmapped areas (obviously it will have a scale problem though).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For hiking maps and an overview map, the Danish company [ScanMaps](http://www.scanmaps.com/english/greenland_maps.php) is a good source of printed maps.  Also try [Harvey/Compukort.](http://www.harveymaps.co.uk/acatalog/Greenland.html)

For town maps, [Greenland.com](http://www.greenland.com/en/explore-greenland.aspx) has interactive online maps. Most towns will also have a free printed tourist map.

[Arctic Umiaq Line](http://www.aul.gl/) provides in-season ferry service on the west coast.

And don't be too down on OpenStreetMaps. The reality in places as remote as most of Greenland is that the printed maps have the same problem as OSM: there may be roads that aren't on the map, and things on the map that have been under the permafrost for 20 years. These things happen when you're a "road less traveled" kind of traveler.

I'd definitely be downloading the OSM maps of Greenland to my iPhone as a just-in-case backup.  Check out the app [Gaia GPS](http://www.gaiagps.com/), which will enable you to download maps for offline use from both OpenStreetMaps and Cloudmade, giving you further comfort since you have two different maps to compare.

Wear warm underwear, and have fun!